# Random item sometime empty or more than on item?

Tags: sql-server

I am randomly generating millions of rows in a table.
When adding a row I want to randomly select one of the rows from the Country table which I show below and get the name to insert it into the table. I don't want the Id of the country I want the name, as this is helping me populate the other table with the name.

The table I am populating is this one:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[User] (
    UserId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    LastName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CreatedDate DATETIME2(2) NOT NULL,
    Reputation INT NOT NULL,
    [Location] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Bio NVARCHAR(4000) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_User PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(UserId)
);
```

I use the Nums table to help me generate lots of rows

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Nums(n INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO dbo.Nums(n)
VALUES(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)
GO
```

This is where I am inserting the millions of rows and I want A Country name put in the Location field.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[User] (FirstName, LastName, CreatedDate, Reputation, [Location], Bio) 
SELECT 'FirstName' + CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (100000), 0) AS VARCHAR(10)), 
'LastName' +  CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (100000), 0) AS VARCHAR(10)),
DATEADD(DAY, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1+DATEDIFF(DAY, '2015-01-01', '2021-06-08')), '2015-01-01'), 
ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (99999) + 1, 0),
-- THIS LINE IS NOT WORKING
(SELECT TOP 1 [Name] FROM Country WHERE CountryId = ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(249-1)+1, 0) ),
N'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
FROM dbo.Nums AS D1
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D2
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D3
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D4
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D5
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D6
ORDER BY D1.n, D2.n, D3.n, D4.n, D5.n, D6.n
```

I have a Country table which has 249 rows, I want to get the country name randomly with this SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Name] FROM Country WHERE CountryId = ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(249-1)+1, 0)
```

But it doesn't always have a value and sometimes has more than 1 value! This is very odd.

I am running this SQL to test it now:

```
SELECT * FROM Country WHERE CountryId = ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(249-1)+1, 0)
```

I get results, multiple results and no results. I must be missing something as I just want the one number and always one number? Why does this line generate these results?

Below I show 3 results from running it:

[image]

The countries are as follows:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[Country] ([Name])
    VALUES ('Afghanistan'),
    ('Åland Islands'),
    ('Albania'),
    ('Algeria'),
    ('American Samoa'),
    ('Andorra'),
    ('Angola'),
    ('Anguilla'),
    ('Antarctica'),
    ('Antigua and Barbuda'),
    ('Argentina'),
    ('Armenia'),
    ('Aruba'),
    ('Australia'),
    ('Austria'),
    ('Azerbaijan'),
    ('Bahrain'),
    ('Bahamas'),
    ('Bangladesh'),
    ('Barbados'),
    ('Belarus'),
    ('Belgium'),
    ('Belize'),
    ('Benin'),
    ('Bermuda'),
    ('Bhutan'),
    ('Bolivia, Plurinational State of'),
    ('Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba'),
    ('Bosnia and Herzegovina'),
    ('Botswana'),
    ('Bouvet Island'),
    ('Brazil'),
    ('British Indian Ocean Territory'),
    ('Brunei Darussalam'),
    ('Bulgaria'),
    ('Burkina Faso'),
    ('Burundi'),
    ('Cambodia'),
    ('Cameroon'),
    ('Canada'),
    ('Cape Verde'),
    ('Cayman Islands'),
    ('Central African Republic'),
    ('Chad'),
    ('Chile'),
    ('China'),
    ('Christmas Island'),
    ('Cocos (Keeling) Islands'),
    ('Colombia'),
    ('Comoros'),
    ('Congo'),
    ('Congo, the Democratic Republic of the'),
    ('Cook Islands'),
    ('Costa Rica'),
    ('Côte d''Ivoire'),
    ('Croatia'),
    ('Cuba'),
    ('Curaçao'),
    ('Cyprus'),
    ('Czech Republic'),
    ('Denmark'),
    ('Djibouti'),
    ('Dominica'),
    ('Dominican Republic'),
    ('Ecuador'),
    ('Egypt'),
    ('El Salvador'),
    ('Equatorial Guinea'),
    ('Eritrea'),
    ('Estonia'),
    ('Ethiopia'),
    ('Falkland Islands (Malvinas)'),
    ('Faroe Islands'),
    ('Fiji'),
    ('Finland'),
    ('France'),
    ('French Guiana'),
    ('French Polynesia'),
    ('French Southern Territories'),
    ('Gabon'),
    ('Gambia'),
    ('Georgia'),
    ('Germany'),
    ('Ghana'),
    ('Gibraltar'),
    ('Greece'),
    ('Greenland'),
    ('Grenada'),
    ('Guadeloupe'),
    ('Guam'),
    ('Guatemala'),
    ('Guernsey'),
    ('Guinea'),
    ('Guinea-Bissau'),
    ('Guyana'),
    ('Haiti'),
    ('Heard Island and McDonald Islands'),
    ('Holy See (Vatican City State)'),
    ('Honduras'),
    ('Hong Kong'),
    ('Hungary'),
    ('Iceland'),
    ('India'),
    ('Indonesia'),
    ('Iran, Islamic Republic of'),
    ('Iraq'),
    ('Ireland'),
    ('Isle of Man'),
    ('Israel'),
    ('Italy'),
    ('Jamaica'),
    ('Japan'),
    ('Jersey'),
    ('Jordan'),
    ('Kazakhstan'),
    ('Kenya'),
    ('Kiribati'),
    ('Korea, Democratic People''s Republic of'),
    ('Korea, Republic of'),
    ('Kuwait'),
    ('Kyrgyzstan'),
    ('Lao People''s Democratic Republic'),
    ('Latvia'),
    ('Lebanon'),
    ('Lesotho'),
    ('Liberia'),
    ('Libya'),
    ('Liechtenstein'),
    ('Lithuania'),
    ('Luxembourg'),
    ('Macao'),
    ('Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of'),
    ('Madagascar'),
    ('Malawi'),
    ('Malaysia'),
    ('Maldives'),
    ('Mali'),
    ('Malta'),
    ('Marshall Islands'),
    ('Martinique'),
    ('Mauritania'),
    ('Mauritius'),
    ('Mayotte'),
    ('Mexico'),
    ('Micronesia, Federated States of'),
    ('Moldova, Republic of'),
    ('Monaco'),
    ('Mongolia'),
    ('Montenegro'),
    ('Montserrat'),
    ('Morocco'),
    ('Mozambique'),
    ('Myanmar'),
    ('Namibia'),
    ('Nauru'),
    ('Nepal'),
    ('Netherlands'),
    ('New Caledonia'),
    ('New Zealand'),
    ('Nicaragua'),
    ('Niger'),
    ('Nigeria'),
    ('Niue'),
    ('Norfolk Island'),
    ('Northern Mariana Islands'),
    ('Norway'),
    ('Oman'),
    ('Pakistan'),
    ('Palau'),
    ('Palestine, State of'),
    ('Panama'),
    ('Papua New Guinea'),
    ('Paraguay'),
    ('Peru'),
    ('Philippines'),
    ('Pitcairn'),
    ('Poland'),
    ('Portugal'),
    ('Puerto Rico'),
    ('Qatar'),
    ('Réunion'),
    ('Romania'),
    ('Russian Federation'),
    ('Rwanda'),
    ('Saint Barthélemy'),
    ('Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha'),
    ('Saint Kitts and Nevis'),
    ('Saint Lucia'),
    ('Saint Martin (French part)'),
    ('Saint Pierre and Miquelon'),
    ('Saint Vincent and the Grenadines'),
    ('Samoa'),
    ('San Marino'),
    ('Sao Tome and Principe'),
    ('Saudi Arabia'),
    ('Senegal'),
    ('Serbia'),
    ('Seychelles'),
    ('Sierra Leone'),
    ('Singapore'),
    ('Sint Maarten (Dutch part)'),
    ('Slovakia'),
    ('Slovenia'),
    ('Solomon Islands'),
    ('Somalia'),
    ('South Africa'),
    ('South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands'),
    ('South Sudan'),
    ('Spain'),
    ('Sri Lanka'),
    ('Sudan'),
    ('Suriname'),
    ('Svalbard and Jan Mayen'),
    ('Swaziland'),
    ('Sweden'),
    ('Switzerland'),
    ('Syrian Arab Republic'),
    ('Taiwan, Province of China'),
    ('Tajikistan'),
    ('Tanzania, United Republic of'),
    ('Thailand'),
    ('Timor-Leste'),
    ('Togo'),
    ('Tokelau'),
    ('Tonga'),
    ('Trinidad and Tobago'),
    ('Tunisia'),
    ('Turkey'),
    ('Turkmenistan'),
    ('Turks and Caicos Islands'),
    ('Tuvalu'),
    ('Uganda'),
    ('Ukraine'),
    ('United Arab Emirates'),
    ('United Kingdom'),
    ('United States'),
    ('United States Minor Outlying Islands'),
    ('Uruguay'),
    ('Uzbekistan'),
    ('Vanuatu'),
    ('Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of'),
    ('Viet Nam'),
    ('Virgin Islands, British'),
    ('Virgin Islands, U.S.'),
    ('Wallis and Futuna'),
    ('Western Sahara'),
    ('Yemen'),
    ('Zambia'),
    ('Zimbabwe')
```

### **Solution - Update**

I thought this was working with the ORDER BY NEWID(), but in fact it was only selecting 4 values so not random at all! As shown here when I grouped and counted the items by Location.

[image]

So this was NOT the answer:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[User] (FirstName, LastName, CreatedDate, Reputation, [Location], Bio) 
SELECT 'FirstName' + CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (100000), 0) AS VARCHAR(10)), 
'LastName' +  CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (100000), 0) AS VARCHAR(10)),
DATEADD(DAY, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1+DATEDIFF(DAY, '2015-01-01', '2021-06-08')), '2015-01-01'), 
ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (99999) + 1, 0),
(SELECT TOP 1 [Name] FROM Country ORDER BY NEWID()),
N'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
FROM dbo.Nums AS D1
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D2
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D3
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D4
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D5
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D6
ORDER BY D1.n, D2.n, D3.n, D4.n, D5.n, D6.n
```

But Stu's answer did work and gave my a more random distribution, so thank you @Stu.

[image]

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[User] (FirstName, LastName, CreatedDate, Reputation, [Location], Bio) 
SELECT 'FirstName' + CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (100000), 0) AS VARCHAR(10)), 
'LastName' +  CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (100000), 0) AS VARCHAR(10)),
DATEADD(DAY, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1+DATEDIFF(DAY, '2015-01-01', '2021-06-08')), '2015-01-01'), 
ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (99999) + 1, 0),
C.[Name],
N'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
FROM dbo.Nums AS D1
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D2
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D3
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D4
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D5
CROSS JOIN dbo.Nums AS D6
CROSS APPLY (values((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 249)+1)) AS RND(R)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 [Name]
    FROM Country AS C
    WHERE C.CountryId = R
) AS C
ORDER BY D1.n, D2.n, D3.n, D4.n, D5.n, D6.n
```

At least one person (Stu) was sticking with me, thanks

Comment: Any reason you're not just using `order by newid()`?

Comment: Because I am populating a table with millions of rows and each row needs a random country

Comment: But that's not what you ask in your question! if you describe your *actual* problem you will be more likely to get an actual solution.

Comment: I've give more context now, but wanted to keep it simple as all i want to know is why this particular select is not returning always 1 row?

Comment: I think you're asking for a solution to an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/); supply a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clearly demonstrates your process; it's inserting the random country name for every row that's your problem, not selecting a single random name.

Comment: Please include how you're generating the millions of rows in the other table. You probably just need a `CROSS APPLY` to select a random country for each incoming row, but without a concrete example of what you're ***actually*** doing, that's just speculation.

Comment: Updated the question with how I am populating the table

Comment: @Andrew I've edited my answer below to include your insert `select` query with the working `country` name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you're generating your set of random rows, however the following is one way you can generate a random country name for each row of a table.

You should be able to apply this to your specific situation as part of an `insert into`.

You can use `apply` to generate the random number and a further `apply` to select the random value per row.

This example simply uses an existing table but generates a random country name for each row and assumes the id values are sequential 1 thru 249:

```
select v.number, c.name
from master.dbo.spt_values v
cross apply (values(Abs(Checksum(NewId())) % 249))x(r)
cross apply (
    select top(1) [name]
    from country c
    where c.id=r
)c
order by v.number
```

See [example on DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e003263f3af45abf4569090b69078e39)

**Edit**

I've amended your current query to include the random month name:

```
with nums as (
    select * from (values(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))x(n)
)
select 'FirstName' + Cast(Round(Rand(Checksum(NewId())) * (100000), 0) as varchar(10)), 
'LastName' +  Cast(Round(Rand(Checksum(NewId())) * (100000), 0) as varchar(10)),
DateAdd(day, Rand(Checksum(NewId()))*(1+DateDiff(day, '2015-01-01', '2021-06-08')), '2015-01-01'), 
Round(Rand(Checksum(NewId())) * (99999) + 1, 0),
c.[name],
N'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing el....'
from Nums as D1
cross join Nums as D2
cross join Nums as D3
cross join Nums as D4
cross join Nums as D5
cross join Nums as D6
cross apply (values((Abs(Checksum(NewId())) % 249)+1))x(r)
cross apply (
    select top(1) [name]
    from country c
    where c.id=r
)c
order by D1.n, D2.n, D3.n, D4.n, D5.n, D6.n
```

Demo [on DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f820d51294d91b1b736a37931d2d6f68)

Comment: Thanks for that @Stu, really appreciate you trying to help, it seems to work for the most part, but in the case of wanting to generate 1 million rows it says its added 9 hundred thousands and something, so with that it doesn't seem give me the number of rows I asked for. Im a bit confused what the x(r) bit is too?

Comment: I also see the CTE has x(n), what is this bit doing?

Comment: @Andrew I tried the full 1m row insert and spotted the reason - I amended above it just needs a +1 for the random number, should have spotted, it was generating 0-248 not 1-249, hence the cross-apply was removing any row where it was zero, so this will now give 1m rows.

Comment: Also the CTE is simply an in-line alternative to your temp table - x is the alias (for the `values` clause) and n is the column name - same for `x(r)`. In the testing I did this was the only reliable way to get a random result per-row so a little conused how the accepted answer works for you, perhaps you can post your final working version? Anyway as long as you have a solution!

Comment: Again thank you Stu, I've update my question with the answer at the bottom, well your answer. The NEWID() approach was not random it was only populating with 4 locations in 1 million rows as shown in the image, but yours did select a random set of data, or at least more random. Thanks for the help, better than other people just closing the question!! Marked yours as the correct solution now.

Comment: Yes I think the rush to close the question was in haste - it definitely needed some clarity to begin with but got there. It could be reopened and someone my offer a better solution, there's always more than one way to skin the proverbial.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to generate an ID at random, you can specify a random sort, and TOP 1.

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Country
ORDER BY NEW_ID();
```

NEW_ID() generates random uniqueidentifiers (one per row), and ordering by that function will induce a random order. Then selecting the first of the randomized rows gives you exactly one random row.

Comment: How is this going to give me a random id from the Country table for a 1 to 249?

Comment: Thanks I see that does work, just didnt make sense at the time, never seen this before! always new things to learn with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

select top 1 * from [Table] order by newid()

```
select top 1 * from Country  order by newid()
```

for better performance, you can use this approach

```
select TOP 1 * FROM Country where CountryId in 
(select top 1 * CountryId from Country order by newid())
```

for limited rows in coutry id between 1 and 249, you can use this:

```
;with LimitedRows
AS
(
   Select * From Country 
   Where CountryId >= 1 and CountryId <=249
)
select top 1 * from LimitedRows order by newid()
```

Comment: How is this going to give me a random id from the Country table for a 1 to 249?

Comment: @Andrew Have you tried it? It should work

Comment: @Andrew then you can select just 1 to 249 ids then get with the second query just query on those items, I will edit the answer in a few seconds.

Comment: Ok so I tried the top one and that did work. But how come that does work I thought newid() will create a new one and it would pass 249 and would then break. Any good links for me to understand why this works? @Charlieface and Milad Dastan Zan

Comment: @Andrew newid() gives a new one GUID each time, So When you use it in order by and just select top 1, it means that in every call you change the order of records, so that works. you can also see this article too: https://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=21

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the calculation is being re-evaluated on every row, therefore it's possible for completely arbitrary results to appear.

Ideally, you should just choose the `TOP 1` `ORDER BY NEWID()` solution, but if you're set on calculating an actual ID, you could store it in a variable first

```sql
DECLARE @id int = ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(249-1)+1, 0);

SELECT TOP 1 [Name]
FROM Country
WHERE CountryId = @id;
```

You may still get no result, because there may not actually be that ID in the table. But you won't get multiple results.

Comment: Assumes that the id column is sequential and contiguous. Any out of order values, gaps, etc, and this approach breaks. Identity columns should never be assumed to behave this 'perfectly', there are too many reasons for gaps to appear.  (`OFFSET` with this approach should be much safer.)

Comment: Have added a note to explain. This is all under the assumption that the IDs are within that range

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface Putting it in a variable with give me a value from 1 - 249? hmm, yet if I put it inline then it wont? still confused why that code didnt work. Ive use the ORDER BY NEWID(), but looking at it, its didnt make sense (special inside knowledge there :) ).